# SimpleDateFormat conversion fails on certain dates

Tags: java, android

So Im trying to convert a date string from one format to another in my Android app. Here's  some code.

```
 final String OLD_FORMAT = "d-MM";
 final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMM d";
 String oldDateString = "06-03";
 Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
 sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
 String newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

This works great and is correctly converted to Mar 06. However, if I change oldDateString to "09-04" it crashes.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09-04" (at offset 0)
```

I'm at loss. Anyone have any ideas what's causing the issue?

I feed the date conversion function with a list with dates and values from the following SQL query.

```
String sql = "SELECT strftime('%d-%m', timestamp) as valDate, COUNT(*) FROM log GROUP BY valDate LIMIT 7";
```

Cheers!

Comment: What's your Java version, timezone/locale and environment?

Comment: I tested with Java 6 and 8 - and it works. Maybe the full code (incl. creation of `SimpleDateformat sdf`) would help.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. Could that be an issue here?

Comment: Ive added the code that feeds the date conversion function. I have no idea why this isnt working :S

Answer (score 0):

So the cause problem was entirely my fault, and had I posted the full code someone would probably have pointed out the issue long ago.

My actual code has a while loop in there as well.. I stripped it out of the original post to sanitize it a bit

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
while (i < 10){
try{
 final String OLD_FORMAT = "d-MM";
 final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMM d";
 String oldDateString = "06-03";
 Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
 sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
 String newDateString = sdf.format(d);
}
 ....
}
```

This resulted in the buggy behavior. However, if I move the sdf definition inside the while section, it works fine, so Ill mark this solved. It would be awesome if someone could explain why it makes a difference though.

Comment: When you call `applyPattern` to change to the new format, the sdf will still have that new format at the top of the next iteration. You'd need to reset it. Personally, I'd use two separate instances of SDF, one for old, one for new (both created before the loop). A method like `applyPattern` should not exist if you ask me.

Answer (score -1):

You can find some examples here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

In this case you have to use dd-MM

EDIT: When the day is from 0 to 9 the right character is 'd', when we have 00 to 09 the right way is 'dd', the same with Months, and years.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `d-MM` and `dd-MM` and why it worked for that first date?

Comment: Forgot to mention Im working with Android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Doesnt seem like I need to use dd. At any rate, I tried and it didnt make any difference, which make sense considering the first date is always parsed correctly.